# AppCompat v21 builds are generated

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appwidget

Why are AppCompat v21 builds being generated even when I am targeting API 15? That causes me a lot of erros because of missing parent styles.

How can I solve it?

Comment: maybe because you are compiling it with v21 sdk

Comment: Targeting has nothing to do with compile SDK.